# Difference in function scope and context

Tags: javascript

Does function in javascript have global and local scope?see the code below

```
function doSomething()
{
    function foo()
{
    alert(this);
}

foo();
}
foo();
```

Here function `foo()` does not get executed. But  the "this" keyword within the function points to global window object,if function `doSomething()` is executed.That means the function `foo()` is executing on the global scope .since it is executing in global scope why cant we execute the nested function directly without first executing the `doSomething()`.

Answer (score 1):

You're confusing scope and context. The first is fixed for the given function (unless it's returned by some function, effectively being injected into the outer scope), the second (which, among other things, defines what `this` refers to inside this function) is given to the function when it's invoked - and in fact can be changed with `call` and `apply`.

Consider this:

```
var someObj = function() {
    var internalObj = {
        nam: 'internal',
        doSomething: function() {
            console.log('Called from ' + this.name);
        }
    }
    internalObj.doSomething('Internal');      // 1
    var someFunc = internalObj.doSomething;
    someFunc();                               // 2
    return {
        nam: 'external',
        doSomething: internalObj.doSomething
    }        
}
var x = new someObj();
x.doSomething();                              // 3
setTimeout(x.doSomething, 1000);              // 4
setTimeout(x.doSomething.bind({nam:'a new one'}), 2000); // 5
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/reEz5/).

In this example we define method 'doSomething' as property of `internalObj` variable, which is local to this constructor function - if you try to access it outside the `someObj`, you'll get ReferenceError.

When method is called in the constructor function itself (1), you'll get 'Called from internal' logged - as the method's context object (`this`) refers to `internalObj` now.

When we assign this method (its reference) to another local variable and call it from there (2), 'undefined' gets logged instead. Scope obviously didn't change here, but context variable did: it refers to the global object now.

Then we return this method as a result of constructor - and things start getting far more interesting: our function is now available in the outer scope! Note, though, the difference between results of its invokations in (3) and (4): the former gives us `external` (as the context object here is the one that was created by the constructor), the latter, again, return us `undefined` even though the syntax is the same. ) It happens because functions sent into timeout and event handlers "lose" their context, in short... unless we fix it with `Function.prototype.bind` method, like in (5).

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript has function level scope.

Any function *declaration* will be scoped to its nearest containing function automatically.

Function expressions just return a value (that is a function) so you can scope them in any way you choose.

> That means the function foo() is executing on the global scope

You are confusing scope and context.

Scope is determined by where a variable is declared (with `var` or a special rule like "function declarations are scoped"). It effects where a variable is visible.

Context is determined by how a function is called. It effects what the value of `this` is.

The two are not connected.

Comment: Does function too have scope?

Comment: Yes. In fact, functions are the only thing that have scopes.